# Identify the dirty region for a Graphics2D when repainting in Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d

When using a `Graphics2D` object, what is the right way to find out which part of the destination buffer needs to be redrawn, or, if the whole buffer needs to be redrawn, what the dimensions of the destination buffer are?

The destination buffer may be a `BufferedImage`, an *AWT* component or the virtual device used when printing. For some operations, like tiling the background with a pattern, it is necessary to know which area needs to be painted even without the intent to optimize repainting.

I tried using `Graphics.getClipBounds()`, but that returns `null` sometimes.

I'm assuming there is some method along the lines of `Rectangle2D getInvaidRegion()` or `Rectangle2D getDestinationBufferSize()`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? What part needs redrawing why?

Comment: @TimB The closest I could find is the equivalent in the _.NET_ framework: [PaintEventArgs.ClipRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.cliprectangle(v=vs.110).aspx). As usual, a description is non-existant, but here is what it does: This property of the event always tells you which part of the backing buffer you need to redraw. This may be the area of the whole buffer or just part of it, if only part of the buffer has been invalidated.

Comment: So this is when a Swing repaint request comes in so you know the dirty area to redraw?

Comment: @TimB Yes, that is one instance where it would be useful. But I'm looking for a solution that also works when the whole component needs to be redrawn or when I'm drawing to something other than a Swing component.

Comment: @TimB Only now I saw that you changed the title and someone else the tags of the question, completely changing the context! I'm not interested in a solution that only when painting a Swing component. I'm asking wether the Java graphics API has a general way of defining which area needs to be actually painted.

Comment: But that question is meaningless without a context to say what dirty means. I only changed the title because swing was in the tags. Did someone else add the swing tag?

Comment: Ahh, I just looked and they did, sorry about that. The answer then is "no". The graphics API as far as I know has no concept of dirty regions, it is about drawing and nothing else. Whatever is calling the graphics API is what keeps track of dirty regions.

Answer (score 1):

In Swing there are a few different ways you can be asked to redraw.

At it's simplest you override `paintComponent` and just draw everything, the borders and sub-components are handled for you.

The next most complicated is to override `paint`. you now need to handle borders and sub components.

Finally you have `paintImmediately` that you can override:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintImmediately%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

This is informed of the dirty area but does very little for you.

Comment: paintImmediately must be called out of EDT, otherwise caused a few awfull exceptions from RepaintManager, then there depends of exceptions tyoe(s), but on some cases the result could be that Swing GUI can be terminated from Task Manager only

Comment: result could be to override `RepaintManager` (can unexpectedly to decide that some pixel(s) can or can't be repainted) or usage repaint (x,x,x,x ....)

Comment: What happens if I draw to a `BufferedImage` or from an implementation of `java.awt.print.Printable.print()`? Do I need to special-case the painting code for each of these cases?